# Swift using generic in protocol

Tags: swift, covariance

For rapid development‘s sake I made protocols called `Message` and `Socket`.

Follow by a real implementation and a mock one. Codes here:

```swift
// Procotols
protocol Message {

}

protocol Socket {
    associatedtype T: Message
    var messages: [T] { get }
}

// Real implementation
class RealMessage: Message {

}

class RealSocket: Socket {
    private(set) var messages: [RealMessage] = []
}

// Mocks
class MockMessage: Message {

}

class MockSocket: Socket {
    private(set) var messages: [MockMessage] = []
}

class VC {
    // Error here: Protocol 'Socket' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
    var socket: Socket = MockSocket()

    // The only way I know to solve this is using the codes below:
    // var socket: MockSocket = MockSocket()
}
```

**My expectation：**

Since I has two set of sockets, I wish I can **switch environment between the mock and the real**, which would be very nicely for development and debugging.

But **there is an error in VC** which stops me from accomplishment.

Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55066079/protocol-line-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint-because-it-has-self-or and many many many others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don’t try to use a generic protocol this way. You could use an ordinary protocol, or a class so as to get inheritance, or a generic class if the generic part is important. But a protocol with a generic associated type is not itself a type.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
class VC <T: Socket>{
    var socket: T
    // Error here: Protocol 'Socket' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

    init(with socket: T) {
        self.socket = socket
    }
    // The only way I know to solve this is using the codes below:
    // var socket: MockSocket = MockSocket()
}

let vc = VC(with: MockSocket())
let vc2 = VC(with: RealSocket())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another field to store the actual messages, and conforms to the protocol via computed value. No associatedtype needed.

```
protocol Socket {
    var messages: [Message] { get }
}

// Real implementation 
class RealSocket: Socket {
    var messages:[Message]{
        return realMessages
    }
    private var realMessages: [RealMessage] = []
}

// Mocks
class MockSocket: Socket {
    var messages:[Message]{
        return mockMessages
    }
    private var mockMessages: [MockMessage] = []
}

class VC {
    var socket: Socket = MockSocket()

}
```